# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setName' of undefined" for channelCreate and channelDelete

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to trigger this event when a channel is added or removed it changes the name of the voice channel but for some reason `.setName` is undefined for trigger events "channelDelete" & "channelCreate" while for "guildMemberAdd" & "guildMemberRemove" it works perfectly fine.

`Broken Code:`

```
client.on('channelCreate', channelX => {
    client.channels.cache.get(vcID).setName(`Channels Count: ${allChannels}`);
});

client.on('channelDelete', channelY => {
    client.channels.cache.get(vcID).setName(`Channels Count: ${allChannels}`);
});
```

`Working Code:`

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', memberX => {
    client.channels.cache.get(MembersVCID).setName(`Member Count: ${totalCount}`);
});

client.on('guildMemberRemove', memberY => {
    client.channels.cache.get(MembersVCID).setName(`Member Count: ${totalCount}`);
});
```

As far as I can see, there is no difference and It's broken for no reason.

`Console Output:`

```
D:\Discord Bots\SampleBot\commands\setup.js:144
            client.channels.cache.get(vcID).setName(`Channels Count: ${allChannels}`);
                                                  ^

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'setName' of undefined
        at Client.<anonymous> (D:\Discord Bots\SampleBot\commands\setup.js:144:51)
        at Client.emit (node:events:394:28)
        at ChannelCreateAction.handle (D:\Discord Bots\SampleBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\ChannelCreate.js:17:14)
        at Object.module.exports [as CHANNEL_CREATE] (D:\Discord Bots\SampleBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\CHANNEL_CREATE.js:4:32)
        at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (D:\Discord Bots\SampleBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
        at WebSocketShard.onPacket (D:\Discord Bots\SampleBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
        at WebSocketShard.onMessage (D:\Discord Bots\SampleBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
        at WebSocket.onMessage (D:\Discord Bots\SampleBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
        at WebSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
        at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (D:\Discord Bots\SampleBot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:970:20)
```

Comment: This means the channel doesn’t exist, or it isn’t in the bot’s cache (it has not interacted with the channel)

Comment: Ofcourse, how stupid of me. I Understand why now. Thanks